# Labeling the multiplicities in class-table mappings

Tags: java, design, sql, orm, relational-database

Trying this again but with a slightly different approach. My previous thread was here [Can anyone explain this one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many concept with respect to ORMs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328793/can-anyone-explain-this-one-to-one-one-to-many-many-to-one-many-to-many-conce) but honestly I think it confused me more than it helped, especially when there seemed to be conflicting views even among the answers / commenters.

I'm not sure if my understanding is correct and I just lacked the vocabulary to express it, or if I have a serious hole somewhere that needs to be resolved with an explicit counter-example.

So I want to try this again with a more explicit example or two.

**Example 1:**

Let's say I defined two classes like so:

```
class A { 
    private String name;
    private List<B> listB;
}

class B {
    private String name;
}
```

Now in this example I have not said anything explicitly (in terms of annotations) about whether the relationships are one to one, one to many in either direction, or many to many. I am going solely from the cardinalities of the containers.

To my understanding, this is a one to many relationship from A to B and the ORM would map this like so:

[image]

**Example 2:**

Let's say I defined two classes like so:

```
class A { 
    private String name;
    private List<B> listB;
}

class B {
    private String name;
    private A referenceA;
}
```

I assume that this ends up with the same table mapping as Example 1.

**Example 3:**

Let's say I defined two classes like so:

```
class A { 
    private String name;
    private List<B> listB;
}

class B {
    private String name;
    private List<A> listA;
}
```

I assume this is a many-to-many relationship, and an ORM would map it like this:

[image]

My question is whether or not my understanding is correct and whether or not this sort of approach results in any ambiguities (and what an example of that might look like).

Comment: You should annotate the relations with the names of the relations. otherwise, its unclear.

Comment: @Polygnome I can't tell if you are trolling or not. This is sort of the entire reason behind me asking this question. If it is unclear, please show a counter-example of how it can be interpreted differently.

Comment: You are assuming that the ORM would map your examples into tables where the relationship is mandatory in the ONE side. The code doesn't say that. The relationship is 0:M not 1:M.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova What? Where do I imply it is mandatory?

Comment: See @christophe 's answer. He also noticed it.

Comment: I still do not understand. Can anyone show me what the models would look like based on the code examples?

Comment: The ER diagram. When a line conects to a table with a litle empty circle next to it, it means its not mandatory. But whete there is a little stroke or line  it means it's mandatory. In the diagram the relatioshio is mandatory in this direction B->A, i.e., you cannot insert a B if there is no corresponding A.

Comment: The circle means possibly 0, the perpendicular notch means 1, I thought. You have an A, with possibly no B's (example 1), but possibly any number of B's. Or are you saying they both need to have circles?

Answer (score 1):

For the examples 1 and 2 you are almost correct.  Some comments:

- In the class association of example 1 you can only navigate from A to B, but not backwards (in an UML class diagram you'd use an arrow for navigability)
- The class association of example 2 is bidirectional: you can always navigate from A to B and vice versa (in an UML class diagram you'd use a line connecting the classes and either a bidirectional arrow or no arrow at all).
- In the relational model, you don't have this subtle difference because relations are **always bidirectional in an RDBMS**. So in fact you can't represent exactly the example 1. You'll always be in the situation of example 2.  The only difference that you would make is that your ORM code won't use the bidirectional navigation.
- The table for B doesn't completely map your classes:  according to your class model you could have a self-standing B not related to an A.  You can't store such a reality in your table, unless either

  - you'd accept a_id could be null keeping your table model.
  - or you'd use 3 tables, you could then be even more accurate and guarantee a sequential ordering of the B's as in the A object's list:  table A (id as primary key, name), table B (id as primary key, name) table AB (id_A and seqno primary key,  id_B foreign key + unique constraint).  This model would look like:
    [image]
    Note that this assumes that if you would have an item B with label "CHOCOLATE" that would appear in several As, there would be several instances of "CHOCOLATE" in B, each having a different id (because we're representing a one to many relationship, and not a many to many relationship).

For the example 3, the relational model doesn't accurately represent your class model:

- Every A has a list of Bs, and every B has a list of As, but there is no guarantee that these are consistent (i.e. reciprocal).  You could for example have an A with an empty list, but conversely having a B  that uses this specific A in its list. Again the relation can be asymmetric in your class model, whereas it is always symmetric in your relational model.
- You could of course decide that an invariant  of your class model is that whenever a B is inserted in the list in an A, this A is reciprocally inserted in the list in B (and same for removal).  In this case your model would be ok as it is (except if the order in each list would matter; you'd then have to ad some sequence numbers).
- Another alternative could be to have two tables A_B and B_A in your relational model in order to represent the asymmetric situation.

In all this I assumed that your class example was in java, where the object's reference are stored in the list, so that they could be shared across several lists:

- in example 1 and 2 I assumed that by construction you would not share the objects.  If you'd allow sharing of B's (e.g. having one "CHOCOLATE" and refering to it in several lists) then you'd be in a unidirectional many to many relationship
- would it be C++, you could make explicit if you share objects (using list of pointers to objects) or not (using list of objects)
- this is why for data modeling, I'd prefer UML which is more expressive than the Entity/Relationship notation:  you could represent the navigability constraints, and you could distinguish aggregation (e.g. sharing of elements/parts) from composition (owned elements/parts that are not shared).

Comment: Can you show me what the models SHOULD look like?

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker the class model or the relational model ?

Comment: Both -- I am trying to understand how things map

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker I've tried to clarify explanation and adding one of the model.  Hope this helps

Comment: If UML is better then by all means -- I am just trying to learn this stuff. If UML is better then I am happy to go with UML

Comment: I don't understand though why the link isn't between id_a (as opposed to this seqno thing)

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker It's a composite primary key formed by id_a AND seqno, so I tried to put it between the two.

Comment: I do not understand -- why is a composite key needed here? I was trying to model a simple many-to-many relationship. Or are you saying that the classes would need to be different for that?

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker It is not needed: it's a choice. I prefer to avoid independent id's for entities that is in reality completely dependent of other entities. Having the composite primary key ensures the unique identification and ensures that the sequential numbering is unique for the elements of a given id_a.

Answer (score 1):

If a ORM were to generate a table from the code you provide this would be the ER diagrams:

For code 1 and 2:

[image]

For code 3:

[image]

The code should have annotations that tell the ORM than the relationships are 1:M and not 0:M.

The red arrows were added  by me to show yoy that the ONE side of the relationship is NOT mandatory, whereas in the diagram your provide it's mandatory, which is not inferable  from the code you provide.

[image]

Hibernate, a popular, ORM may need you to add an annotation similar to this on class B to let it know that the relationship from B to A is mandatory (I don't use Hibernate, so anyone feel free to correct it):

```
@Column(name = "a_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
private A referenceA;
```

Comment: "The code should have annotations that tell the ORM than the relationships are 1:M and not 0:M" Why? How do you know when it is 1:M vs. 0:M? What would the classes have to look like to make it 1:M?

Comment: @Basically there's nothing in your classes that FORCES you to have a non-null reference from B to A. So the ORM shouldn't map it to a relationship where you are FORCED to have a corresponding A before inserting a B. The model the ORM would generate, like your classes, would allow you to have stand-alone `B`s, or stand-alone `A_B`s.

Comment: But if an object exists, doesn't that imply that it's already non-null to some degree? Or would I have to explicitly designate (somehow) in the class that the id field is non-null? I assumed this was default behavior or expected default behavior or something?

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker A variable is not an object. It can be null.

Comment: Are you referring to the possible case `A someObject = null;`? Or are you talking explicitly in terms of ID?

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker If you were using  a tool where you draw a class diagram and it generates a ER model, compositions (black diamond) would map to 1:M relationships and aggregations (white diamond) would map to 0:M relationships. But as you are using non-annotated classes, the relationship (ER diagram) would non mandatory in both directions.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of your ORM framework. Not all of them work the same. There are some things that can't simply be infered from code and you have to help the ORM know what you want via annotations in the code.

Comment: I'm not using any specific ORM -- I am trying to make a basic one for my own use / practice so I can understand how they work up close. It is very hard to find good materials online explaining how this stuff works (way too abstract, not enough explicit examples)

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker For creating such a tool you need to separatelly master both OOP/D and database design.

Comment: That's what I am trying to learn with these examples -- to understand how classes map to table relationships, and what additional information is needed through things like annotations.

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker Try using an existing ORM and experiment to see how they map things. It's the scientific method.

Comment: The existing ORMs are far too complex (or incomplete) -- I already tried that. Hence why I am starting from simplicity here and working my way up

Comment: Can you please show what you mean exactly when you mention this null case? What kind of annotation are you referring to here? An annotation on the entire class itself?

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker I added an example at the end of the answer.

Comment: This is what I was asking earlier though in the third comment. :( So you *are* referring to an ID field in particular (and _not_ the object/reference being null?). But this gets to the question I was trying to word: If we don't say "nullable=false" then this means it is possible the a_id field is null, which means we could make object B with a null object A reference, correct?

Comment: It means that you could insert a row in B leaving A_ID null and the RDBMS will allow it.

Comment: Right, yes, that is what I mean. What I am asking is: What does that look like in terms of the class? An object B where its referenceA member is null? Or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44254/discussion-between-tulains-cordova-and-the-29th-saltshaker).